# Stuck on a mate in 3

Tags: problems

I've been stuck on this for the longest time. At this point I would just like confirmation it is possible.

```
[Title "White mates in 3"]
[FEN "8/8/8/2N5/8/2k1N3/Q3r2q/K7 w - - 0 1"]
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To explain how you can answer this question yourself without spoiling the answer:

1. Go to lichess.org/analysis
2. Paste your FEN into the FEN box, or set up the board manually.
3. Under the hamburger menu, turn off "best move arrow" and set "multiple lines" to 0.

[image]

Now, switch on local analysis, and you will see the evaluation is #3. This tells you that white does indeed have a mate in 3.

[image]

Answer (score 11):

The mate you are looking for arises after

```
[Title "White mates in 3"]
[FEN "8/8/8/2N5/8/2k1N3/Q3r2q/K7 w - - 0 1"]

1. Qc4+ Kd2 2. Qc1+ Kxc1 3. Nb3#.
```

It features a decoy queen sac and the rare two knights mate.